# How i can use mysql rows value as attribute?

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table and i want to use rows value if row value is value_2 as attribute billow is example :
Table 1:

```
Attribute_1 Attribute_2  Attribute_3
1             Value_2      10
2             Value_2      20
3             Value_1      30
```

I want result as billow :

```
Attribute_1 Value_2  
1            10
2            20
```

You help is appreciable

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking to you sample seems you are looking for an alias

```
select Attribute_1 , Attribute_3 as Value
from my_table
```

AND don't use 
`-` minus  use underscore `_` if you need  or use backticks for column with space `Attribute 1`

Update for the changed  question

```
select Attribute_1 , Attribute_2 as Value_2
from my_table
where Attribute_2 ='value_2'
```

but you should not change the original question otherwise  the others users can't understand the answer  properly ..

Comment: Attribute-1 Is a example i have change it. Thanks for your answer l am checking.

Comment: i have updated my question please check. Is it possible?

Comment: answer  update  .. but remember that chnage the question is not fair and creates confusion in other users